# TypeError: is not a function in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling a method in angular but I am getting this error :

> TypeError: this.saveCoordinates is not a function

Could you please help me to understand ? This is the code :

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor( public http: HttpClient) {
   }

  public saveCoordinates(){
    ///post request here 
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/api/tutorials', {
        "title":lat,
        "description":ling
        }).subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data)
    })
    ///post request here
      }
  ngOnInit() {
     map.on('click', function(e) {
      this.saveCoordinates()
        });
  }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback). More specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/38931751#38931751) using arrow functions.

Comment: You forgot to add lat and ling when you call your function

Comment: @Juany  still having the same error even after adding it

Comment: @R.Richards i already checked it and removed this identifier but still having the same error

Comment: replace 
 ngOnInit() {
     map.on('click', function(e) {
      this.saveCoordinates()
        });
  }

with 

 ngOnInit() {
var self  = this;     
map.on('click', function(e) {
      self.saveCoordinates()
        });
  }

because on click callback this represent different scope

Comment: @ShahidAhmad please add you code as an answer it's working and I will approve it , thanks

Comment: in ngonit you are  listening for an event and in event callback this reference to different scope due to which it gives you this type errors so you need to save the reference of this in a variable before this event binding and then instead of this used that variable to call that function on it  
to know about the scope of this in different scenario please check the below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @يومياتتلــميذتونــسي question is marked duplicate that's why I can't add an answer to your question